# create pdf invoice using fpdf

Tags: php, wordpress, fpdf

> PDF Invoice attachment with mail using FPDF
>   first download fpdf from here "www.fpdf.org/en/download.php"  and copy folder to your on drive where you want pdf
>
> Invoice.php

```
<?php
  require('../fpdf181/fpdf.php');
define('EURO', chr(128) );
define('EURO_VAL', 6.55957 );
class PDF_Invoice extends FPDF
{
    // private variables
 var $colonnes;
 var $format;
 var $angle=0;

 // private functions
 function RoundedRect($x, $y, $w, $h, $r, $style = '')
 {
   $k = $this->k;
  $hp = $this->h;
  if($style=='F')
    $op='f';
 elseif($style=='FD' || $style=='DF')
    $op='B';
 else
    $op='S';
 $MyArc = 4/3 * (sqrt(2) - 1);
 $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F m',($x+$r)*$k,($hp-$y)*$k ));
 $xc = $x+$w-$r ;
 $yc = $y+$r;
 $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F l', $xc*$k,($hp-$y)*$k ));

 $this->_Arc($xc + $r*$MyArc, $yc - $r, $xc + $r, $yc - $r*$MyArc, $xc + $r,  $yc);
$xc = $x+$w-$r ;
$yc = $y+$h-$r;
$this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F l',($x+$w)*$k,($hp-$yc)*$k));
$this->_Arc($xc + $r, $yc + $r*$MyArc, $xc + $r*$MyArc, $yc + $r, $xc, $yc + $r);
$xc = $x+$r ;
$yc = $y+$h-$r;
$this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F l',$xc*$k,($hp-($y+$h))*$k));
$this->_Arc($xc - $r*$MyArc, $yc + $r, $xc - $r, $yc + $r*$MyArc, $xc - $r, $yc);
$xc = $x+$r ;
$yc = $y+$r;
$this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F l',($x)*$k,($hp-$yc)*$k ));
$this->_Arc($xc - $r, $yc - $r*$MyArc, $xc - $r*$MyArc, $yc - $r, $xc, $yc - $r);
$this->_out($op);
 }
function _Arc($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3)
{
 $h = $this->h;
 $this->_out(sprintf('%.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F %.2F c ', $x1*$this->k, ($h-$y1)*$this->k,
 $x2*$this->k, ($h-$y2)*$this->k, $x3*$this->k, ($h-$y3)*$this->k));
}
function Rotate($angle, $x=-1, $y=-1)
{
 if($x==-1)
    $x=$this->x;
 if($y==-1)
    $y=$this->y;
 if($this->angle!=0)
    $this->_out('Q');
 $this->angle=$angle;
 if($angle!=0)
 {
    $angle*=M_PI/180;
    $c=cos($angle);
    $s=sin($angle);
    $cx=$x*$this->k;
    $cy=($this->h-$y)*$this->k;
    $this->_out(sprintf('q %.5F %.5F %.5F %.5F %.2F %.2F cm 1 0 0 1 %.2F %.2F cm',$c,$s,-$s,$c,$cx,$cy,-$cx,-$cy));
  }
 }
 function _endpage()
 {
   if($this->angle!=0)
   {
     $this->angle=0;
    $this->_out('Q');
   }
   parent::_endpage();
 }
 // public functions
function sizeOfText( $texte, $largeur )
{
 $index    = 0;
 $nb_lines = 0;
 $loop     = TRUE;
 while ( $loop )
 {
    $pos = strpos($texte, "\n");
    if (!$pos)
    {
        $loop  = FALSE;
        $ligne = $texte;
    }
    else
    {
        $ligne  = substr( $texte, $index, $pos);
        $texte = substr( $texte, $pos+1 );
    }
    $length = floor( $this->GetStringWidth( $ligne ) );
    $res = 1 + floor( $length / $largeur) ;
    $nb_lines += $res;
 }
 return $nb_lines;
}
// Company
function addSociete( $nom, $adresse )
{
  $x1 = 10;
  $y1 = 40;
   //Positionnement en bas
  $this->SetXY( $x1, $y1 );
  $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
  $length = $this->GetStringWidth( $nom );
  $this->Cell( $length, 2, $nom);
  $this->SetXY( $x1, $y1 + 4 );
  $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
  $length = $this->GetStringWidth( $adresse );
  //Coordonnées de la société
  $lignes = $this->sizeOfText( $adresse, $length) ;
  $this->MultiCell($length, 4, $adresse);
 }
 // Label and number of invoice/estimate
 function fact_dev( $libelle, $num )
 {
    $r1  = $this->w - 80;
    $r2  = $r1 + 68;
    $y1  = 6;
    $y2  = $y1 + 2;
    $mid = ($r1 + $r2 ) / 2;
    $texte  = $libelle . " EN " . EURO . " N° : " . $num;    
    $szfont = 12;
    $loop   = 0;
    while ( $loop == 0 )
    {
      $this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", $szfont );
      $sz = $this->GetStringWidth( $texte );
      if ( ($r1+$sz) > $r2 )
      $szfont --;
      else
       $loop ++;
    }
   $this->SetLineWidth(0.1);
   $this->SetFillColor(192);
   $this->RoundedRect($r1, $y1, ($r2 - $r1), $y2, 2.5, 'DF');
   $this->SetXY( $r1+1, $y1+2);
   $this->Cell($r2-$r1 -1,5, $texte, 0, 0, "C" );
  }
  // Estimate
 function addDevis( $numdev )
 {
    $string = sprintf("DEV%04d",$numdev);
    $this->fact_dev( "Devis", $string );
 }
 // Invoice
 function addFacture( $numfact )
 {
    $string = sprintf("FA%04d",$numfact);
    $this->fact_dev( "Facture", $string );
 }
 function addDate( $date )
 {
    $r1  = $this->w - 61;
    $r2  = $r1 + 30;
    $y1  = 17;
    $y2  = $y1 ;
    $mid = $y1 + ($y2 / 2);
    $this->RoundedRect($r1, $y1, ($r2 - $r1), $y2, 3.5, 'D');
    $this->Line( $r1, $mid, $r2, $mid);
    $this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2-$r1)/2 - 5, $y1+3 );
    $this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 10);
    $this->Cell(10,5, "DATE", 0, 0, "C");
    $this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2-$r1)/2 - 5, $y1+9 );
    $this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 10);
    $this->Cell(10,5,$date, 0,0, "C");
  }
function addClient( $ref )
{
$r1  = $this->w - 31;
$r2  = $r1 + 19;
$y1  = 17;
$y2  = $y1;
$mid = $y1 + ($y2 / 2);
$this->RoundedRect($r1, $y1, ($r2 - $r1), $y2, 3.5, 'D');
$this->Line( $r1, $mid, $r2, $mid);
$this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2-$r1)/2 - 5, $y1+3 );
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 10);
$this->Cell(10,5, "CLIENT", 0, 0, "C");
$this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2-$r1)/2 - 5, $y1 + 9 );
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 10);
$this->Cell(10,5,$ref, 0,0, "C");
}

function addPageNumber( $page )
{
$r1  = $this->w - 80;
$r2  = $r1 + 19;
$y1  = 17;
$y2  = $y1;
$mid = $y1 + ($y2 / 2);
$this->RoundedRect($r1, $y1, ($r2 - $r1), $y2, 3.5, 'D');
$this->Line( $r1, $mid, $r2, $mid);
$this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2-$r1)/2 - 5, $y1+3 );
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 10);
$this->Cell(10,5, "PAGE", 0, 0, "C");
$this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2-$r1)/2 - 5, $y1 + 9 );
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 10);
$this->Cell(10,5,$page, 0,0, "C");
}

// Client address
function addClientAdresse( $nom, $adresse )
{
$r1     = $this->w - 80;
$r2     = $r1 + 68;
$y1     = 40;
/*$this->SetXY( $r1, $y1);
$this->MultiCell( 60, 4, $adresse);*/
//$x1 = 10;
//$y1 = 247;
//Positionnement en bas
$this->SetXY( $r1, $y1 );
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$length = $this->GetStringWidth( $nom );
$this->Cell( $length, 2, $nom);
$this->SetXY( $r1, $y1 + 4 );
$this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$length = $this->GetStringWidth( $adresse );
//Coordonnées de la société
$lignes = $this->sizeOfText( $adresse, $length) ;
$this->MultiCell($length, 4, $adresse);
}

// Mode of payment
function addReglement( $mode )
{
$r1  = 10;
$r2  = $r1 + 60;
$y1  = 80;
$y2  = $y1+10;
$mid = $y1 + (($y2-$y1) / 2);
$this->RoundedRect($r1, $y1, ($r2 - $r1), ($y2-$y1), 2.5, 'D');
$this->Line( $r1, $mid, $r2, $mid);
$this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2-$r1)/2 -5 , $y1+1 );
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 10);
$this->Cell(10,4, "BUYER NAME", 0, 0, "C");
$this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2-$r1)/2 -5 , $y1 + 5 );
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 10);
$this->Cell(10,5,$mode, 0,0, "C");
}

// Expiry date
function addEcheance( $date )
{
$r1  = 80;
$r2  = $r1 + 40;
$y1  = 80;
$y2  = $y1+10;
$mid = $y1 + (($y2-$y1) / 2);
$this->RoundedRect($r1, $y1, ($r2 - $r1), ($y2-$y1), 2.5, 'D');
$this->Line( $r1, $mid, $r2, $mid);
$this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2 - $r1)/2 - 5 , $y1+1 );
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 10);
$this->Cell(10,4, "DATE", 0, 0, "C");
  $this->SetXY( $r1 + ($r2-$r1)/2 - 5 , $y1 + 5 );
  $this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 10);
 $this->Cell(10,5,$date, 0,0, "C");
}

// VAT number
function addNumTVA($tva)
{
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 10);
$r1  = $this->w - 80;
$r2  = $r1 + 70;
$y1  = 80;
$y2  = $y1+10;
$mid = $y1 + (($y2-$y1) / 2);
$this->RoundedRect($r1, $y1, ($r2 - $r1), ($y2-$y1), 2.5, 'D');
$this->Line( $r1, $mid, $r2, $mid);
$this->SetXY( $r1 + 16 , $y1+1 );
$this->Cell(40, 4, "SHIPPING DATE", '', '', "C");
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 10);
$this->SetXY( $r1 + 16 , $y1+5 );
$this->Cell(40, 5, $tva, '', '', "C");
}

function addReference($ref)
{
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 10);
$length = $this->GetStringWidth( "Références : " . $ref );
$r1  = 10;
$r2  = $r1 + $length;
$y1  = 92;
$y2  = $y1+5;
$this->SetXY( $r1 , $y1 );
$this->Cell($length,4, "Références : " . $ref);
}

function addCols( $tab )
{
global $colonnes;

$r1  = 10;
$r2  = $this->w - ($r1 * 2) ;
$y1  = 100;
$y2  = $this->h - 50 - $y1;
$this->SetXY( $r1, $y1 );
$this->Rect( $r1, $y1, $r2, $y2, "D");
$this->Line( $r1, $y1+6, $r1+$r2, $y1+6);
$colX = $r1;
$colonnes = $tab;
while ( list( $lib, $pos ) = each ($tab) )
{
    $this->SetXY( $colX, $y1+2 );
    $this->Cell( $pos, 1, $lib, 0, 0, "C");
    $colX += $pos;
    $this->Line( $colX, $y1, $colX, $y1+$y2);
}
}

function addLineFormat( $tab )
{
 global $format, $colonnes;

while ( list( $lib, $pos ) = each ($colonnes) )
{
    if ( isset( $tab["$lib"] ) )
        $format[ $lib ] = $tab["$lib"];
}
}

function lineVert( $tab )
{
global $colonnes;

reset( $colonnes );
$maxSize=0;
while ( list( $lib, $pos ) = each ($colonnes) )
{
    $texte = $tab[ $lib ];
    $longCell  = $pos -2;
    $size = $this->sizeOfText( $texte, $longCell );
    if ($size > $maxSize)
        $maxSize = $size;
}
return $maxSize;
}

// add a line to the invoice/estimate
/*    $ligne = array( "REFERENCE"    => $prod["ref"],
                  "DESIGNATION"  => $libelle,
                  "QUANTITE"     => sprintf( "%.2F", $prod["qte"]) ,
                  "P.U. HT"      => sprintf( "%.2F", $prod["px_unit"]),
                  "MONTANT H.T." => sprintf ( "%.2F", $prod["qte"] * $prod["px_unit"]) ,
                  "TVA"          => $prod["tva"] );
   */
    function addLine( $ligne, $tab )
    {
     global $colonnes, $format;

      $ordonnee     = 10;
$maxSize      = $ligne;

reset( $colonnes );
while ( list( $lib, $pos ) = each ($colonnes) )
{
    $longCell  = $pos -2;
    $texte     = $tab[ $lib ];
    $length    = $this->GetStringWidth( $texte );
    $tailleTexte = $this->sizeOfText( $texte, $length );
    $formText  = $format[ $lib ];
    $this->SetXY( $ordonnee, $ligne-1);
    $this->MultiCell( $longCell, 4 , $texte, 0, $formText);
    if ( $maxSize < ($this->GetY()  ) )
        $maxSize = $this->GetY() ;
    $ordonnee += $pos;
}
return ( $maxSize - $ligne );}


function addRemarque($remarque)


{
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 10);
$length = $this->GetStringWidth( "Remarque : " . $remarque );
$r1  = 10;
$r2  = $r1 + $length;
$y1  = $this->h - 45.5;
$y2  = $y1+5;
$this->SetXY( $r1 , $y1 );
$this->Cell($length,4, "Remarque : " . $remarque);
}
function addCadreTVAs()
{
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 8);
$r1  = 10;
$r2  = $r1 + 120;
$y1  = $this->h - 40;
$y2  = $y1+20;
$this->RoundedRect($r1, $y1, ($r2 - $r1), ($y2-$y1), 2.5, 'D');
$this->Line( $r1, $y1+4, $r2, $y1+4);
$this->Line( $r1+5,  $y1+4, $r1+5, $y2); // avant BASES HT
$this->Line( $r1+27, $y1, $r1+27, $y2);  // avant REMISE
$this->Line( $r1+43, $y1, $r1+43, $y2);  // avant MT TVA
$this->Line( $r1+63, $y1, $r1+63, $y2);  // avant % TVA
$this->Line( $r1+75, $y1, $r1+75, $y2);  // avant PORT
$this->Line( $r1+91, $y1, $r1+91, $y2);  // avant TOTAUX
$this->SetXY( $r1+9, $y1);
$this->Cell(10,4, "BASES HT");
$this->SetX( $r1+29 );
$this->Cell(10,4, "REMISE");
$this->SetX( $r1+48 );
$this->Cell(10,4, "MT TVA");
$this->SetX( $r1+63 );
$this->Cell(10,4, "% TVA");
$this->SetX( $r1+78 );
$this->Cell(10,4, "PORT");
$this->SetX( $r1+100 );
$this->Cell(10,4, "TOTAUX");
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 6);
$this->SetXY( $r1+93, $y2 - 8 );
$this->Cell(6,0, "H.T.   :");
$this->SetXY( $r1+93, $y2 - 3 );
$this->Cell(6,0, "T.V.A. :");
}

function addCadreEurosFrancs()
{
$r1  = $this->w - 70;
$r2  = $r1 + 60;
$y1  = $this->h - 40;
$y2  = $y1+20;
$this->RoundedRect($r1, $y1, ($r2 - $r1), ($y2-$y1), 2.5, 'D');
$this->Line( $r1+20,  $y1, $r1+20, $y2); // avant EUROS
$this->Line( $r1+20, $y1+4, $r2, $y1+4); // Sous Euros & Francs
$this->Line( $r1+38,  $y1, $r1+38, $y2); // Entre Euros & Francs
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 8);
$this->SetXY( $r1+22, $y1 );
$this->Cell(15,4, "EUROS", 0, 0, "C");
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 8);
$this->SetXY( $r1+42, $y1 );
$this->Cell(15,4, "FRANCS", 0, 0, "C");
$this->SetFont( "Arial", "B", 6);
$this->SetXY( $r1, $y1+5 );
$this->Cell(20,4, "TOTAL TTC", 0, 0, "C");
$this->SetXY( $r1, $y1+10 );
$this->Cell(20,4, "ACOMPTE", 0, 0, "C");
$this->SetXY( $r1, $y1+15 );
$this->Cell(20,4, "NET A PAYER", 0, 0, "C");
}

// remplit les cadres TVA / Totaux et la remarque
// params  = array( "RemiseGlobale" => [0|1],
//"remise_tva"     => [1|2...],  // {la remise s'applique sur ce code TVA}
// "remise"         => value,     // {montant de la remise}
//"remise_percent" => percent,   // {pourcentage de remise sur ce montant de TVA}
//                  "FraisPort"     => [0|1],
//                      "portTTC"        => value,     // montant des frais  de ports TTC
//                                                     // par defaut la TVA = 19.6 %
//                      "portHT"         => value,     // montant des frais de ports HT
//                      "portTVA"        => tva_value, // valeur de la TVA a appliquer sur le montant HT
//                  "AccompteExige" => [0|1],
//                      "accompte"         => value    // montant de l'acompte (TTC)
//                      "accompte_percent" => percent  // pourcentage d'acompte (TTC)
//                  "Remarque" => "texte"              // texte
// tab_tva = array( "1"       => 19.6,
//                  "2"       => 5.5, ... );
// invoice = array( "px_unit" => value,
//                  "qte"     => qte,
//                  "tva"     => code_tva );
function addTVAs( $params, $tab_tva, $invoice )
{
$this->SetFont('Arial','',8);

reset ($invoice);
$px = array();
while ( list( $k, $prod) = each( $invoice ) )
{
    $tva = $prod["tva"];
    @ $px[$tva] += $prod["qte"] * $prod["px_unit"];
}

$prix     = array();
$totalHT  = 0;
$totalTTC = 0;
$totalTVA = 0;
$y = 261;
reset ($px);
natsort( $px );
while ( list($code_tva, $articleHT) = each( $px ) )
{
    $tva = $tab_tva[$code_tva];
    $this->SetXY(17, $y);
    $this->Cell( 19,4, sprintf("%0.2F", $articleHT),'', '','R' );
    if ( $params["RemiseGlobale"]==1 )
    {
        if ( $params["remise_tva"] == $code_tva )
        {
            $this->SetXY( 37.5, $y );
            if ($params["remise"] > 0 )
            {
                if ( is_int( $params["remise"] ) )
                    $l_remise = $param["remise"];
                else
                    $l_remise = sprintf ("%0.2F", $params["remise"]);
                $this->Cell( 14.5,4, $l_remise, '', '', 'R' );
                $articleHT -= $params["remise"];
            }
            else if ( $params["remise_percent"] > 0 )
            {
                $rp = $params["remise_percent"];
                if ( $rp > 1 )
                    $rp /= 100;
                $rabais = $articleHT * $rp;
                $articleHT -= $rabais;
                if ( is_int($rabais) )
                    $l_remise = $rabais;
                else
                    $l_remise = sprintf ("%0.2F", $rabais);
                $this->Cell( 14.5,4, $l_remise, '', '', 'R' );
            }
            else
                $this->Cell( 14.5,4, "ErrorRem", '', '', 'R' );
        }
    }
    $totalHT += $articleHT;
    $totalTTC += $articleHT * ( 1 + $tva/100 );
    $tmp_tva = $articleHT * $tva/100;
    $a_tva[ $code_tva ] = $tmp_tva;
    $totalTVA += $tmp_tva;
    $this->SetXY(11, $y);
    $this->Cell( 5,4, $code_tva);
    $this->SetXY(53, $y);
    $this->Cell( 19,4, sprintf("%0.2F",$tmp_tva),'', '' ,'R');
    $this->SetXY(74, $y);
    $this->Cell( 10,4, sprintf("%0.2F",$tva) ,'', '', 'R');
    $y+=4;
 }

 if ( $params["FraisPort"] == 1 )
 {
    if ( $params["portTTC"] > 0 )
    {
        $pTTC = sprintf("%0.2F", $params["portTTC"]);
        $pHT  = sprintf("%0.2F", $pTTC / 1.196);
        $pTVA = sprintf("%0.2F", $pHT * 0.196);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',6);
        $this->SetXY(85, 261 );
        $this->Cell( 6 ,4, "HT : ", '', '', '');
        $this->SetXY(92, 261 );
        $this->Cell( 9 ,4, $pHT, '', '', 'R');
        $this->SetXY(85, 265 );
        $this->Cell( 6 ,4, "TVA : ", '', '', '');
        $this->SetXY(92, 265 );
        $this->Cell( 9 ,4, $pTVA, '', '', 'R');
        $this->SetXY(85, 269 );
        $this->Cell( 6 ,4, "TTC : ", '', '', '');
        $this->SetXY(92, 269 );
        $this->Cell( 9 ,4, $pTTC, '', '', 'R');
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
        $totalHT += $pHT;
        $totalTVA += $pTVA;
        $totalTTC += $pTTC;
    }
    else if ( $params["portHT"] > 0 )
    {
        $pHT  = sprintf("%0.2F", $params["portHT"]);
        $pTVA = sprintf("%0.2F", $params["portTVA"] * $pHT / 100 );
        $pTTC = sprintf("%0.2F", $pHT + $pTVA);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',6);
        $this->SetXY(85, 261 );
        $this->Cell( 6 ,4, "HT : ", '', '', '');
        $this->SetXY(92, 261 );
        $this->Cell( 9 ,4, $pHT, '', '', 'R');
        $this->SetXY(85, 265 );
        $this->Cell( 6 ,4, "TVA : ", '', '', '');
        $this->SetXY(92, 265 );
        $this->Cell( 9 ,4, $pTVA, '', '', 'R');
        $this->SetXY(85, 269 );
        $this->Cell( 6 ,4, "TTC : ", '', '', '');
        $this->SetXY(92, 269 );
        $this->Cell( 9 ,4, $pTTC, '', '', 'R');
        $this->SetFont('Arial','',8);
        $totalHT += $pHT;
        $totalTVA += $pTVA;
        $totalTTC += $pTTC;
    }
  }

  $this->SetXY(114,266.4);
  $this->Cell(15,4, sprintf("%0.2F", $totalHT), '', '', 'R' );
  $this->SetXY(114,271.4);
  $this->Cell(15,4, sprintf("%0.2F", $totalTVA), '', '', 'R' );

  $params["totalHT"] = $totalHT;
  $params["TVA"] = $totalTVA;
  $accompteTTC=0;
  if ( $params["AccompteExige"] == 1 )
  {
    if ( $params["accompte"] > 0 )
    {
        $accompteTTC=sprintf ("%.2F", $params["accompte"]);
        if ( strlen ($params["Remarque"]) == 0 )
            $this->addRemarque( "Accompte de $accompteTTC Euros exigé à la commande.");
        else
            $this->addRemarque( $params["Remarque"] );
    }
    else if ( $params["accompte_percent"] > 0 )
    {
        $percent = $params["accompte_percent"];
        if ( $percent > 1 )
            $percent /= 100;
        $accompteTTC=sprintf("%.2F", $totalTTC * $percent);
        $percent100 = $percent * 100;
        if ( strlen ($params["Remarque"]) == 0 )
            $this->addRemarque( "Accompte de $percent100 % (soit $accompteTTC Euros) exigé à la commande." );
        else
            $this->addRemarque( $params["Remarque"] );
    }
    else
        $this->addRemarque( "Drôle d'acompte !!! " . $params["Remarque"]);
  }
  else
  {
    if ( strlen ($params["Remarque"]) > 0 )
        $this->addRemarque( $params["Remarque"] );
  }
  $re  = $this->w - 50;
  $rf  = $this->w - 29;
  $y1  = $this->h - 40;
  $this->SetFont( "Arial", "", 8);
  $this->SetXY( $re, $y1+5 );
  $this->Cell( 17,4, sprintf("%0.2F", $totalTTC), '', '', 'R');
  $this->SetXY( $re, $y1+10 );
  $this->Cell( 17,4, sprintf("%0.2F", $accompteTTC), '', '', 'R');
  $this->SetXY( $re, $y1+14.8 );
  $this->Cell( 17,4, sprintf("%0.2F", $totalTTC - $accompteTTC), '', '', 'R');
  $this->SetXY( $rf, $y1+5 );
  $this->Cell( 17,4, sprintf("%0.2F", $totalTTC * EURO_VAL), '', '', 'R');
  $this->SetXY( $rf, $y1+10 );
  $this->Cell( 17,4, sprintf("%0.2F", $accompteTTC * EURO_VAL), '', '', 'R');
  $this->SetXY( $rf, $y1+14.8 );
  $this->Cell( 17,4, sprintf("%0.2F", ($totalTTC - $accompteTTC) * EURO_VAL), '', '', 'R');
} 

// add a watermark (temporary estimate, DUPLICATA...)
// call this method first
function temporaire( $texte )
{
 $this->SetFont('Arial','B',35);
 $this->SetTextColor(242,242,242);
 $this->Rotate(45,55,190);
 $this->Text(55,190,$texte);
 $this->Rotate(0);
 $this->SetTextColor(0,0,0,0.1);
}
}?>
```

> PHP-Generator.php with mail code

```
    <?php

include ('../../../../wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
    $order_id=$_POST['order_id'];
    $selected_val=$_POST['selected_val'];
    $dreason=$_POST['dreason'];
    $product_name_semail=$_POST['product_name_semail'];
    $order_price_semail=$_POST['order_price_semail'];
    $species_name_semail=$_POST['species_name_semail'];
    $finish_name_semail=$_POST['finish_name_semail'];
    $order_date_semail=$_POST['order_date_semail'];
    $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'matched_order_details';
    $order_table=$wpdb->prefix.'buyer_order_request';
    $matched_table=$wpdb->prefix.'matched_order_details';
    $query="SELECT * FROM $matched_table INNER JOIN $order_table ON $matched_table.id =$order_id";
    $results=$wpdb->get_results($query);
    $match_buyer_id=$results[0]->buyer_id;
    $match_supplier_id=$results[0]->order_supplier_id;
    $match_supplier_id;
    $supplier_data=get_userdata($match_supplier_id);
    $buyer_data=get_userdata($match_buyer_id);
    $buyer_mail=$buyer_data->user_email;
    $buyer_name=$buyer_data->user_login;
    $supplier_mail=$supplier_data->user_email;

    require('invoice.php');

$pdf = new PDF_Invoice( 'P', 'mm', 'A4' );
$pdf->AddPage();
$reportName="Product Order Invoice";    
$pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 17 );
$pdf->Cell( 0, 15, $reportName, 0, 1, 'C' );
$pdf->addSociete( "MaSociete",
              "MonAdresse\n" .
              "75000 PARIS\n".
              "R.C.S. PARIS B 000 000 007\n" .
              "Capital : 18000 " . EURO );

$pdf->temporaire( "Flatrock Technology Ecommerce" );
$today = date('d/m/Y');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->addClientAdresse( "MaSociete",
              "MonAdresse\n" .
              "75000 PARIS\n".
              "R.C.S. PARIS B 000 000 007\n" .
              "Capital : 18000 " . EURO );
$pdf->addReglement($buyer_name);
$pdf->addEcheance($today);
$pdf->addNumTVA("05/11/2004");
//$pdf->addReference("Devis ... du ....");
$cols=array( "S.NO"    => 9,
         "PRODUCT NAME"=> 46,
         "SPECIES NAME"=> 42,
         "FINISH NAME"=> 38,
         "ORDER DATE" => 30,
         "PRICE"=> 25 );
$pdf->addCols( $cols);

$cols=array( "S.NO"    => "L",
         "PRODUCT NAME"=> "C",
         "SPECIES NAME"=> "C",
         "FINISH NAME"=> "C",
         "ORDER DATE" => "C",
         "PRICE"=> "C" );
$pdf->addLineFormat( $cols);

$y    = 109;
$line = array( "S.NO"    => "1",
           "PRODUCT NAME"  => $product_name_semail,
           "SPECIES NAME"     => $species_name_semail,
           "FINISH NAME"      => $finish_name_semail,
           "ORDER DATE" => $order_date_semail,
           "PRICE"          =>$order_price_semail );
$size = $pdf->addLine( $y, $line );
$y   += $size + 2;
$pdf->SetXY( 10, 247 );
$pdf->Cell(165,8,'Total Price:',1,0,'R');
$pdf->Cell(25,8,$order_price_semail,1,1,'C');

$tot_prods = array( array ( "px_unit" => 600, "qte" => 1, "tva" => 1 ),
                array ( "px_unit" =>  10, "qte" => 1, "tva" => 1 ));
$tab_tva = array( "1"       => 19.6,
              "2"       => 5.5);
$params  = array( "RemiseGlobale" => 1,
                  "remise_tva"     => 1,       // {la remise s'applique sur ce code TVA}
                  "remise"         => 0,       // {montant de la remise}
                  "remise_percent" => 10,      // {pourcentage de remise sur ce montant de TVA}
              "FraisPort"     => 1,
                  "portTTC"        => 10,      // montant des frais de ports TTC
                                               // par defaut la TVA = 19.6 %
                  "portHT"         => 0,       // montant des frais de ports HT
                  "portTVA"        => 19.6,    // valeur de la TVA a appliquer sur le montant HT
              "AccompteExige" => 1,
                  "accompte"         => 0,     // montant de l'acompte (TTC)
                  "accompte_percent" => 15,    // pourcentage d'acompte (TTC)
              "Remarque" => "Avec un acompte, svp..." );


    $filename="/home-path/plugins/plugin-name/folder-name/order-".$order_id.".pdf";

    $opt=$pdf->Output($filename,'F');

            $to   = $buyer_mail;
            $from = $supplier_mail;
            $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
            $headers.= "CC: v.tamrakar@laxyosolutionsoft.com\r\n";
            $headers.= "BCC: $from\r\n";
            $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $message = '<html><body>';

            $message .= '<table width="100%"; rules="all" style="border:1px solid #3A5896; padding-left:20px">';
            $message .= '<span style="font-size: 14px;margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 7px 10px; background:#999999; color:#ffffff; float:left; margin-right:5px;">Order Confirmation </span>';
            $message .= "<tr><td><h1>Dear $buyer_data->user_login,</h1><br /><br /><tr><td>We Are Heartly Thanks To You. You can Choose Me For Your Order.<br>Your Order Details Here</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td style='font-size:14px;'>Product Details<br /><br /></td><tr><td style='width:20%'>Product Name: $product_name_semail</td></tr>";
            $message.='<tr><td style="width:20%">Category: '. $species_name_semail.'</td></td>';
            $message.='<tr><td style="width:20%">Size: '.$finish_name_semail.'</td>';
            $message.="<tr><td style='width:20%'>Price: $order_price_semail</td>";
            $message.="<tr><td style='width:20%'>Shipping Date: $order_date_semail</td>";
            $attachments = array(  WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/plugin-name/folder-name/order-'.$order_id.'.pdf' );   
            $message .= "<tr><td style='font-size:12px'><br><I>Thanks & Regards<br>$supplier_data->user_login</I></td><br><br></tr>"; 
            $message .= "</table>";
            $message .= "</body></html>";

            wp_mail( $to, 'test mail ', $message, $headers,$attachments);
```

?>

Comment: This is more an answer than a question.

Comment: So what is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: i am solved this problem and put my code to another coder who phase this type of problem

Answer (score 1):

> PHP-Generator.php with mail code

```
<?php

include ('../../../../wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
    $order_id=$_POST['order_id'];
    $selected_val=$_POST['selected_val'];
    $dreason=$_POST['dreason'];
    $product_name_semail=$_POST['product_name_semail'];
    $order_price_semail=$_POST['order_price_semail'];
    $species_name_semail=$_POST['species_name_semail'];
    $finish_name_semail=$_POST['finish_name_semail'];
    $order_date_semail=$_POST['order_date_semail'];
    $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'matched_order_details';
    $order_table=$wpdb->prefix.'buyer_order_request';
    $matched_table=$wpdb->prefix.'matched_order_details';
    $query="SELECT * FROM $matched_table INNER JOIN $order_table ON $matched_table.id =$order_id";
    $results=$wpdb->get_results($query);
    $match_buyer_id=$results[0]->buyer_id;
    $match_supplier_id=$results[0]->order_supplier_id;
    $match_supplier_id;
    $supplier_data=get_userdata($match_supplier_id);
    $buyer_data=get_userdata($match_buyer_id);
    $buyer_mail=$buyer_data->user_email;
    $buyer_name=$buyer_data->user_login;
    $supplier_mail=$supplier_data->user_email;

    require('invoice.php');

$pdf = new PDF_Invoice( 'P', 'mm', 'A4' );
$pdf->AddPage();
$reportName="Product Order Invoice";    
$pdf->SetFont( 'Arial', '', 17 );
$pdf->Cell( 0, 15, $reportName, 0, 1, 'C' );
$pdf->addSociete( "MaSociete",
              "MonAdresse\n" .
              "75000 PARIS\n".
              "R.C.S. PARIS B 000 000 007\n" .
              "Capital : 18000 " . EURO );

$pdf->temporaire( "Flatrock Technology Ecommerce" );
$today = date('d/m/Y');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->addClientAdresse( "MaSociete",
              "MonAdresse\n" .
              "75000 PARIS\n".
              "R.C.S. PARIS B 000 000 007\n" .
              "Capital : 18000 " . EURO );
$pdf->addReglement($buyer_name);
$pdf->addEcheance($today);
$pdf->addNumTVA("05/11/2004");
//$pdf->addReference("Devis ... du ....");
$cols=array( "S.NO"    => 9,
         "PRODUCT NAME"=> 46,
         "SPECIES NAME"=> 42,
         "FINISH NAME"=> 38,
         "ORDER DATE" => 30,
         "PRICE"=> 25 );
$pdf->addCols( $cols);

$cols=array( "S.NO"    => "L",
         "PRODUCT NAME"=> "C",
         "SPECIES NAME"=> "C",
         "FINISH NAME"=> "C",
         "ORDER DATE" => "C",
         "PRICE"=> "C" );
$pdf->addLineFormat( $cols);

$y    = 109;
$line = array( "S.NO"    => "1",
           "PRODUCT NAME"  => $product_name_semail,
           "SPECIES NAME"     => $species_name_semail,
           "FINISH NAME"      => $finish_name_semail,
           "ORDER DATE" => $order_date_semail,
           "PRICE"          =>$order_price_semail );
$size = $pdf->addLine( $y, $line );
$y   += $size + 2;
$pdf->SetXY( 10, 247 );
$pdf->Cell(165,8,'Total Price:',1,0,'R');
$pdf->Cell(25,8,$order_price_semail,1,1,'C');

$tot_prods = array( array ( "px_unit" => 600, "qte" => 1, "tva" => 1 ),
                array ( "px_unit" =>  10, "qte" => 1, "tva" => 1 ));
$tab_tva = array( "1"       => 19.6,
              "2"       => 5.5);
$params  = array( "RemiseGlobale" => 1,
                  "remise_tva"     => 1,       // {la remise s'applique sur ce code TVA}
                  "remise"         => 0,       // {montant de la remise}
                  "remise_percent" => 10,      // {pourcentage de remise sur ce montant de TVA}
              "FraisPort"     => 1,
                  "portTTC"        => 10,      // montant des frais de ports TTC
                                               // par defaut la TVA = 19.6 %
                  "portHT"         => 0,       // montant des frais de ports HT
                  "portTVA"        => 19.6,    // valeur de la TVA a appliquer sur le montant HT
              "AccompteExige" => 1,
                  "accompte"         => 0,     // montant de l'acompte (TTC)
                  "accompte_percent" => 15,    // pourcentage d'acompte (TTC)
              "Remarque" => "Avec un acompte, svp..." );


    $filename="/home-path/plugins/plugin-name/folder-name/order-".$order_id.".pdf";

    $opt=$pdf->Output($filename,'F');

            $to   = $buyer_mail;
            $from = $supplier_mail;
            $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
            $headers.= "CC: v.tamrakar@laxyosolutionsoft.com\r\n";
            $headers.= "BCC: $from\r\n";
            $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $message = '<html><body>';

            $message .= '<table width="100%"; rules="all" style="border:1px solid #3A5896; padding-left:20px">';
            $message .= '<span style="font-size: 14px;margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 7px 10px; background:#999999; color:#ffffff; float:left; margin-right:5px;">Order Confirmation </span>';
            $message .= "<tr><td><h1>Dear $buyer_data->user_login,</h1><br /><br /><tr><td>We Are Heartly Thanks To You. You can Choose Me For Your Order.<br>Your Order Details Here</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td style='font-size:14px;'>Product Details<br /><br /></td><tr><td style='width:20%'>Product Name: $product_name_semail</td></tr>";
            $message.='<tr><td style="width:20%">Category: '. $species_name_semail.'</td></td>';
            $message.='<tr><td style="width:20%">Size: '.$finish_name_semail.'</td>';
            $message.="<tr><td style='width:20%'>Price: $order_price_semail</td>";
            $message.="<tr><td style='width:20%'>Shipping Date: $order_date_semail</td>";
            $attachments = array(  WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/plugin-name/folder-name/order-'.$order_id.'.pdf' );   
            $message .= "<tr><td style='font-size:12px'><br><I>Thanks & Regards<br>$supplier_data->user_login</I></td><br><br></tr>"; 
            $message .= "</table>";
            $message .= "</body></html>";

            wp_mail( $to, 'test mail ', $message, $headers,$attachments);
```